# Android with horizontal swipe to close activity, causes white background under softkeyboard

Tags: android

For chat we use custom background. Previously we set our background to activity window.
`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.chat_background);`
Then I tried to make horizontal swipe to close activity like in iPhones. For this to work I needed to set background inside layout. Everything worked, except: when user clicks on input field in activity, it firstly shows white background in the area where softkeyboard will be placed. And on some phones it looks ugly. How I can prevent this white background.

Manifest activity related code:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.ContentActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"
            android:screenOrientation="user"
            />
```

Theme used for activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
contentWrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_background);

chatWrapper.setListener(new ChatFrameLayout.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onTouchIntercept(MotionEvent event) {
                handleChatWrapperOnTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
}

private void handleChatWrapperOnTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Get finger position on screen
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                // Init finger and view position
                previousFingerPositionY = Y;
                previousFingerPositionX = X;
                verticalMove = 0;
                horizontalMove = 0;
                allowLongPress = true;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                if (closeActivity) {
                    chatWrapper.setProceedTouchEventToChild(false);
                    rootView.animate().setListener(animationListener()).x(rootView.getWidth()).setDuration(100);
                } else if (rootView.getX() != 0) {
                    rootView.setX(0);
                    layoutManager.setScrollEnabled(true);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Change base layout size and position (must change position because view anchor is top left corner)
                verticalMove += (Y - previousFingerPositionY);
                horizontalMove += (X - previousFingerPositionX);
                if (horizontalMove > Math.abs(verticalMove)) {
                    //disable horizontal swipe
                    if (horizontalMove > MIN_DISTANCE_TO_START_MOVE) {
                        allowLongPress = false;
                        verticalMove = 0;
                        layoutManager.setScrollEnabled(false);
                        rootView.setX(horizontalMove);
                    }

                    previousFingerPositionY = Y;
                    previousFingerPositionX = X;

                    // Has user scroll enough to "auto close" activity ?
                    if (LayoutHelper.pxToDp(Math.abs(rootView.getX())) > DISMISS_DISTANCE) {
                        closeActivity = true;
                    } else {
                        closeActivity = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    horizontalMove = 0;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Layout code:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/transition_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_primary"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            >

            <include layout="@layout/partial_toolbar"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <View
                style="@style/ToolbarShadow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
                />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/content_overlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: when we set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to an activity in manifest, when the keyboard appears it will try to resize the whole activity which involves redrawing of all the views and in case of some heavy layouts, there will be considerable amount of lag casing in the keyboard area. Alternatively, try if `"adjustPan"` is enough for your need.

Comment: `adjustPan ` didn't make difference, it still shows white background.